# perform ajax on link click on Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, safari

The code below performs ajax request whenever a link is clicked. It first performs request and then follows the link specified in href. This works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox or Safari, such code doesn't successfully post data for reasons unknown to me. What would be the workaround for these 2 browsers?

```
$(".submit-link").click(function(e){



var value=$.trim($(".url-submit").val());
 if(value.length>0){
     //initialize  name and email


 $.ajax({
   url: "getPOST.php",
   type: 'POST',
    data: {"id":value,"name":nameValue, "email":emailValue},
   success: function(response) {
console.log(response); //nothing gets printed in console when using Firefox or Safari, but in Chrome it works as expected
    }


//go to link in href now
 });
    }else{
//do something else
e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no if statement but there is an else statement. Can you edit your script ?

Comment: Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 0):

Just lets make the code more simple;

```
 $(".submit-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $.trim($(".url-submit").val());
        if (value.length > 0) {
            //initialize  name and email
            $.ajax({
                url: "getPOST.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { "id": value, "name": nameValue, "email": emailValue },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    window.location = $('.submit-link').attr('href'); //Assumed your element that has submit-link class also contains the href attribute
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

After you completed your ajax request, now you can go to link.

I added `e.preventDefault();` at the start of function. If the value length greater than "0" it will make the ajax request and after the ajax request completed user will be redirected to link.

Also check your `value` to be sure it has length greater than "0".